# How to avoid error "Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'" pandas 0.16.0

Tags: pandas

I have various dataframes with this format

```
df.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2009-10-23, ..., 2010-06-15]
Length: 161, Freq: None, Timezone: None
df.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')
```

every now and then, at the execution of this line:

```
zeros_idx = df[ (df.A==0) | (df.B==0) | (df.C==0) | (df.D==0) ].index
```

I get the following error with this stack trace:

```
  zeros_idx = df[ (df.A==0) | (df.B==0) | (df.C==0) | (df.D==0) ].index
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 811, in f
  return self._combine_series(other, na_op, fill_value, axis, level)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3158, in _combine_series
  return self._combine_match_columns(other, func, level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3191, in _combine_match_columns
  left, right = self.align(other, join='outer', axis=1, level=level, copy=False)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3143, in align
  fill_axis=fill_axis)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3225, in _align_series
  return_indexers=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1810, in join
  return_indexers=return_indexers)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 904, in join
  return_indexers=return_indexers)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1820, in join
  return_indexers=return_indexers)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1830, in join
  return_indexers=return_indexers)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2083, in _join_monotonic
  join_index, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(sv, ov)
File "pandas/src/generated.pyx", line 8558, in pandas.algos.outer_join_indexer_object (pandas/algos.c:157803)
File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 823, in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas/tslib.c:15585)
  TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'
```

Comment: Are you saying it non-deterministic?  If you execute that line multiple times consecutively, do you sometimes get the error and sometimes not?  It's much easy to help you if you have a reproducible example that's a simple as possible.

Comment: Of course I know, but the dataframes this happens for are all in an expected format, and from 1 run to the next, the same dataframe that failed before, will not fail again.
If I wrap that line with a try: except: , can I get more than the above while

Comment: ... handling the exception?

Comment: Well, one way to isolate the issue is to cut down the number of things happening in the line.  Currently, there's comparisons, bitwise OR, `__getitem__`, accessing the attribute `index` and assignment.  What if you change the line to `(df.A==0)` and put it in a for loop that repeats 100 times.  Do you still get the error?

Comment: Or a better idea, seperate that one command onto as many lines as you can, then rerun the program, and then you can edit your question to have a line with less happening.

Comment: It's really impossible to answer this question without knowing what dtypes are expected, and if not as expected, why not?  I.e. does the timestamp actually represent a datetime, and if so it can't really be zero, right?  Given your code of `df.A==0`, are you expecting dtype to be int or float for all columns?  Use `info()` or `dtypes()` to see what the dtypes are and then go from there in terms of asking the question or solving it yourself.

Comment: I have managed to determine the dataframe for which this problem happens, df.dtype shows that the column D is repeated. D appears twice in .dtype, as opposed to all the other frames that execute successfully. All columns types are float64.